# Query about Guava ListenableFuture

Tags: java, concurrency, guava, future

I am writing a service that calls a few external services. I am using futures to represent the result of all those external service calls. I collapse all the futures to a single future using Futures.successfulAsList() method provided by Guava library.

Here is my code

```
List<ListenableFuture<List<T>>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int id: shardIds) {
    ListeningExecutorService service =
          (ListeningExecutorService) _shardMgr.getExecutorService(id);
    SelectTask task = new SelectTask(_shardMgr.getReadHandle(id), sql, mapper);


    ListenableFuture<List<T>> future = service.submit(task);
    //Add Callback
    Futures.addCallback(future, new ErrorCallBack(task),
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    futureList.add(future);
}

ListenableFuture<List<List<T>>> combinedFuture =
        Futures.successfulAsList(futureList);
int timeout = _dbTimeout.get();
List<T> selectResult = new ArrayList<T>();

try {
    List<List<T>> result = combinedFuture.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    for(List<T> sublist: result) {
        for(T t : sublist) {
            //TODO: Do we want to put a cap on how many results we return here?
            //I think we should
            selectResult.add(t);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    log.error("******************* Exception in parallelSelect ",ex);
    throw new RuntimeException("Error in parallelSelect");
}
```

When one of my future ( external service call ) fails ErrorCallBack's onFailure() is called, But i still get past of combinedFuture.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);  and i get NullPointerException in line for(T t : sublist) ... while iterating over the results.

I expect that when one external service call fails, i should not get past combinedFuture.get()

Am i doing something wrong ? I even tried to throw Exception from ErrorCallBack's onFailure method.

Here is ErrorCallBack's implementation

```
private class ErrorCallBack<T> implements FutureCallback<List<T>>  {
    private final SelectTask _task;

    public ErrorCallBack(SelectTask task) {
        _task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        log.error("ErrorCallBack:onFailure(). Enter");
        DBErrorType type = DBErrorType.UNKNOWN;
        try {
            log.error("ErrorCallBack:onFailure(). Exception ",t);
            if(t instanceof InterruptedException || t instanceof CancellationException) {
                type = DBErrorType.UNKNOWN;
            } else if ( t instanceof SQLException || t.getCause() instanceof SQLException) {
                type = DBErrorType.SQL_SYNTAX_ERROR;
            } else if ( t instanceof MySQLSyntaxErrorException || t.getCause() instanceof MySQLSyntaxErrorException) {
                type = DBErrorType.SQL_SYNTAX_ERROR;
            } else if ( t instanceof ExecutionException) {
                type = DBErrorType.SQL_SYNTAX_ERROR;
            } else if (t instanceof TimeoutException) {
                type = DBErrorType.NETWORK_ERROR;
            } else {
                type = DBErrorType.UNKNOWN;
            }
            ShardHandle handle = _task.getShardHandle();
            _shardMgr.reportException(handle, type);
            DBException exception = new DBException(handle.getShardInfo(), type, ErrorSeverity.CRITICAL, t);
            _alertModule.handleAlert(exception.getAlertContext());
        } catch( Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<T> result) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expect that when one external service call fails, i should not get past combinedFuture.get()

Well, no, since you're calling `Futures.succcessfulAsList()` which, as its name implies, [returns the results of the successful Futures](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList%28java.lang.Iterable%29) (and null for those that failed). For the behaviour you want, you should call [`Futures.allAsList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList%28java.lang.Iterable%29) which gives you a `Future` that fails if any of its components fail.

Since you're not checking for nulls in the results, you get the NPE.